# SQL COUNT certain rows depending on different IDs

Tags: sql, count

Currently i have two count functions, 1 showing the count of all record including NULLS and the other to show only those with a value. I would like to be able to count the number of records of the pcf.ID depending on which ca.ServiceID it is. So for example, i only want to count the pcf.IDs - 7,14,15,25 for ca.ServiceID - 71. Not sure if this is something i could using cases or where to start with it. Is this possible within a single Query? I will need to put this information into a Matrix in SSRS aswell showing all of the services, not sure if that makes any difference to how to approach. Any help would be massively appreciated :)

Currently the first count, counts all records and the second count, counts all those with a value. I would like it to count values based on the Service ID like below.
If serviceID is 71 only count rows with pcf.ID of 7,14,15,25 etc. and return the count value. And do this for all of the different ServiceIDs.

```
SELECT
 COUNT(*)AS [CountAll]
,(COUNT(pcfd.LookupId) + (COUNT(pcfd.TextValue))) As [Answered]
,pcf.ID AS [Field_ID]
,ca.CourseID
,pcf.Label
,pcfd.TextValue
,pcfd.LookupId
,cs.ContractID
,Contract.Name AS [Contract Name]
,Service.Name AS [Service Name]
,ca.ServiceID
,p.ID
FROM
pcfd
INNER JOIN pcf
  ON pcfd.pcfID = pcf.ID
INNER JOIN p
  ON pcfd.pID = p.ID
INNER JOIN ca
  ON p.ID = ca.pID
INNER JOIN Service
  ON ca.ServiceID = Service.ID
INNER JOIN cs
  ON Service.ID = cs.ServiceID
INNER JOIN Contract
  ON cs.ContractID = Contract.ID
WHERE pcf.ID IN (7,14,15,25,12,8,24,23,22)
GROUP BY ca.pID
,ca.CourseID
,pcf.Label
,pcfd.TextValue
,pcfd.LookupId
,p.ID
,ca.ServiceID
,cs.ContractID
,cs.ServiceID
,Service.ID
,Contract.Name
,Service.Name
,pcf.ID
```

Comment: edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can add to the select statement

```
,SUM(CASE WHEN  pcf.IDs IN ( 7,14,15,25) AND  ca.ServiceID = 71 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CountField
```